# how to pass generic type to superclass in dart?

Tags: dart

I have code like this

```
class Human<T> {  // <--- this is the superclass
  final String name;
  final T belongings;

  Human({
    required this.name,
    required this.belongings,
  });
}

class Athlete<T> extends Human { // <--- this is the subclass
  final String sportType;

  Athlete({
    required String name,
    required belongings,
    required this.sportType,
  }) : super(name: name, belongings: belongings);
}

final messi = Athlete<List<String>>( // <--- past List<String> as generic
  name: "Lionel Messi",
  belongings: ["Jersey", "Shoes"],
  sportType: "Football",
);

final belonging = messi.belongings; // <-- the data type is dynamic, not List<String>
```

as you can see, I want `belongings` property to be generic, but after I pass `List<String>` as a generic type when instantiating an Athlete model, I still get `dynamic` data type like the image below, I expect it will be `List<String>` .

[image]

Comment: `class Athlete<T> extends Human` is shorthand for `class Athlete<T> extends Human<dynamic>`.  You want `class Athlete<T> extends Human<T>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `<T>` to `Human`, so it's `extends Human<T>`.

You also need to type the `required belongings,` parameter, either as
`required T belongings,`, or by using the new super-parameters feature and make it `required super.belongings`.

That is:

```dart
class Human<T> {
  final String name;
  final T belongings;

  Human({
    required this.name,
    required this.belongings,
  });
}

class Athlete<T> extends Human<T> { // <--- added <T>
  final String sportType;

  Athlete({
    required super.name,        // <--- used super.name
    required super.belongings,  // <--- used super.longings
    required this.sportType,    
  }); // <--- no constructor call needed when it's all "super." parameters.
}

final messi = Athlete<List<String>>(
  name: "Lionel Messi",
  belongings: ["Jersey", "Shoes"],
  sportType: "Football",
);
```

Comment: thanks Irn, I miss that `<T>` on the subclass declaration. may I know which dart you use?  because I can't use that new super-parameters feature

Comment: The super parameters were introduced in Dart 2.17. Your package needs to have an SDK-dependency of at least 2.17.0 in the `pubspec.yaml` file to enable the new features.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare belongings as a List within the human class like this:

```
final List<String> belongings;

Human({required this.belongings})
```

Comment: More specifically, you should declare the type of your belongings as type T, so that it matches the passed-in generic type.  You might want to narrow T to be <T extends List> so that you'll get at least some autocompletions and weird generic protection.